# Passing a vector of objects to pthread_create

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, pthreads, parameter-passing

How can i pass a vector of objects to pthread_create function ?

I have this code:

```
#define THREAD_NUMBER 1000

void* threadRoom (std::vector <Room*> &rooms){

some code here....
}

int main () {

std::vector <Room*> rooms;
std::vector <pthread_t> workers(THREAD_NUMBER);
pthread_create(&workers[0], NULL, threadRoom, &rooms);

return 0;
}
```

I`m getting these errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(std::vector<Room*>&)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
pthread_create(&worker[0], NULL, threadRoom, &rooms);

note: initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread
```

Comment: You're passing a pointer to `rooms` to `pthread_create` but your `threadRoom` function is expecting a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes.  `pthread_create()` requires its third argument to have type `void* (*)(void *)`, and you're passing an argument of type `void* (*)(std::vector<Room*>&)`.  These are not compatible. The declared argument type for your thread function must be `void *`.

You can cast the actual (pointer) argument to type `void *`, and have `threadRoom()` cast it back to the expected type.  That's not typesafe, but it is in fact the expected usage (though it's a C API, and C doesn't require the casts).